# Editing existing checkout panes

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to add some more fields to some of the existing checkout panes, but have found little information on that topic. So far I've found plenty on how to create my own panes, but I don't want to reinvent the entire pane just because I want to add more fields.

I have found no way to edit the panes via the UI, so I expect this has to be done programmatically, with a hook.

What hook should I look for, for modifying existing checkout panes?

**Specific details**
I want to add fields to the Shipping and Payment Information panes, specifically I want to add fields to the address fields already present in those panes.
The address forms should have a checkbox in the top, which determines the visibility of the other fields (basically if it's a private person or a company, if company is selected then additional fields are displayed using drupals field state api)